# Call Class in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

How to call a Class in a Function (Flex 4)?

Example:

```
public class A {
  private function a();
  private function b();
  ....
}
```

This is my question-->

```
private function loadMain() {


    **call class A in here**

}
```

Who have any ideas ??? 
Thank for watching

Comment: 1. You need an instance of a class A on which you can invoke the methods a and b / 2. But a and b are private in the scope of A, so loadMain needs to be a method of A as well, or a and b need to be public. This may help: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_02.html

Comment: Could you please eloborate? Call methods of Class A you mean? Or instantiate the class A?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

Class A:

```
public class A {
    public function a();
    public function b();
}
```

Function loadMain:

```
private function loadMain() {
    var instance:A = new A();
    instance.a();
    instance.b();
}
```